# Transparency vs Same Color

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, colors, transparency

These two scenarios will produce the exact same visual effect, however I'm not sure which one is better. The end result is the user sees a background through a view on an activity.

1. The activity background is a known solid color. A view that is shown in the layout has a transparent background.
2. The activity background is a known solid color. A view that is shown in the layout has a background consisting of the same solid color as the activities background.

My explicit question is, which one is better?

Comment: the 2th. Drawing transparency is heavy

Comment: If you post as an answer I'll mark it correct